# How to prevent token to get sold for certain period of time?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

Does anybody know how can we prevent a token from being sold in dex? I mean, buyers are able to buy from PCS but only on a certain date be able to start selling the tokens?

I have implemented IERC20, and uniswap interfaces

Also here is my core contract _transfer function:

```
  function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
    require(sender != address(0), "BEP20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "BEP20: transfer to the zero address");
    require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
    //require(sellingIsEnabled, "Bep20: selling not started yet");
    bool isSell = recipient == uniswapV2Pair;
    bool isBuy = sender == uniswapV2Pair;

    require(!isSell || (sender == owner()));

    if (isSell) {
        if(sellingIsEnabled)
        {
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        }else{
            swapTokensForEth(0);
        }
    }
    if (isBuy) {
        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        return;
    }
    //super.Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

    _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "BEP20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
    _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

  }
```

and this is the swap function(i think it has something with selling the token based on uniswap documentation, but I'm not sure):

```
    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        // make the swap
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETH(
            tokenAmount,
            0, // accept any amount of ETH
            path,
            address(this), // The contract
            block.timestamp
        );
        
        emit SwapTokensForETH(tokenAmount, path);
    }
```

note:

```
bool public sellingIsEnabled = true;
```

but when I make `sellingIsEnabled` to `false` , the sell transaction still happens.
how can I prevent token get sold if `!sellingIsEnabled`  ?

Comment: You have to be more specific. Sold where? Uniswap? A centralized exchange? In your custom smart contract?

Comment: you could implement a vesting contract that get the token instead of accounts and then make them claimable by the account after a certain date.

Comment: To @MajdTL's point, see [Sablier](https://sablier.finance). Disclaimer: I'm the founder.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I meant sold on dex.